# AJAX post doesn't send data .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have the below script. `@username` is a variable that comes from the model.

```
  <script>
                    var username = "@username"
                    $.ajax({

                          url: '@Url.Action("fetchChatsForUser")',
                          data: { Username: username },
                          type: "POST",
                          dataType: 'JSON',
                          contentType: "application/json",
                          success: function (e) {
                              console.log(e);
                              $("#Chatroom").html(e)
                          },
                          error: function (passParams) {
                              console.log("Error is " + passParams);
                          }
                      })

</script>
```

I checked the value of `username` and its not empty or null it's working. However in my controller when the `fetchChatsForUser` gets called by `ajax`, the data that's sent is null.
here is the controller

```
public IActionResult fetchChatsForUser(string Username)
    {
        Chat Chats = new Chat();
        
        return PartialView("_Chatroom", Chats);
    }
```

The `string Username` in controller is always null even though im passing data in ajax. The method does get called though. What am I doing wrong here

Comment: it's still null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ajax use POST and your function is Get. So you need to put [HttpPost]

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult fetchChatsForUser(string Username)
```

Or you try this jquery one.

```
<script>
var username = "@username";
$.post('@Url.Action("fetchChatsForUser")', { Username: username }).done(function (e) {
   console.log(e);
   $("#Chatroom").html(e);
});
</script>
```

Comment: this solved the issue. I have another function that calls the same method in my controller. now that doesnt work `$(document).on("click", ".shadow-inner.block.rounded-l.h-auto.border-b-2.mt-2.cursor-pointer", function () {
            $.post('@Url.Action("fetchChatsForUser")', { Username: $(this).data("username") }).done(function (e) {
                $("#Chatroom").html(e);
            })`

Comment: you just put new css class name in your button instead of typing many css classes. Like, <a class='btn-fetch-user' data-username='test'>View</a>. $(document).on("click", ".btn-fetch-user", function () { }); and also make sure that your button's data-username has value.

Comment: other way is to add function to your button. <a onclick='FetchUser(this);' data-username='test'>View</a>. function FetchUser(btn) { $.post(....); }

Comment: Does this solve your problem? If solved, can mark this as solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is from body, so you can change like this.

Ajax, add `JSON.stringify(username)`.

```
                var username = "@username"
                $.ajax({

                      url: '@Url.Action("fetchChatsForUser")',

                      data: JSON.stringify(username),
                      type: "POST",
                      dataType: 'JSON',
                      contentType: "application/json",
                      success: function (e) {
                          console.log(e);
                          //$("#Chatroom").html(e)
                      },
                      error: function (passParams) {
                          console.log("Error is " + passParams);
                      }
                  })
```

Bakend

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult fetchChatsForUser([FromBody]string Username)
    {
        Chat Chats = new Chat();

        return PartialView("_Chatroom", Chats);
        
    }
```

Result

[image]