# I'm new in ASP.NET CORE, and I'm trying to send data from dynamically created input fields to Controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core

```js
$("#addRow").click(function () 
         {
             @{
                 new VLSM_Model().LansValues.Add(new Lans());
             }
             var rowCount = parseInt($("#totalLans").val());
             rowCount++;
             $("#totalLans").val(rowCount);
                var html = '';
                html += '<div id="inputFormRow" style="width: 35%">';
                html += '<div class="input-group mb-3">';
                html += '<input type="number" id="[' + (rowCount - 1) + '].InitialLanValues" class="form-control m-input" placeholder="Enter number of Hosts" autocomplete="off" style="width: 30%" required>';
                html += '<div class="input-group-append">';
                html += '<button id="removeRow" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" style="margin-right: 5px">Remove Network</button>';
                html += '</div>';
                html += '</div>';
        
                $('#newRow').append(html);
            });
        
            $(document).on('click', '#removeRow', function () 
            {
                var rowCount = parseInt($("#totalLans").val());
                rowCount--;
                $("#totalLans").val(rowCount);
                $(this).closest('#inputFormRow').remove();
            });
            
            $(document).ready(function () {  
                    $("#createButton").click(function () 
                    {
                        var inputData = $(this).serializeArray();
                        $.ajax(  
                        {  
                            type: "POST", //HTTP POST Method  
                            url: "VLSM_Controller/Create", // Controller/View   
                            data: inputData,
                            success : function(response) {
                              console.log(response)
                            }
                        });  
              
                    });  
                });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>VLSM CALCULATE</h1>
<hr />
<form asp-action="Create">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group" style="width: 35%">
                <label asp-for="IP_Address" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="IP_Address" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="IP_Address" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <br/>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div id="inputFormRow" style="width: 35%">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <br/>
                    <div class="input-group-append"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="newRow">
                 <input type="hidden" id="totalLans" value="0" />
            </div>
            <button id="addRow" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Add Network</button>
            
        </div>
            <span asp-validation-for="LansValues" class="text-danger"></span>
            <br/>
            <div class="form-group" style="width: 35%">
                <label asp-for="cidrValue" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="cidrValue" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="cidrValue" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Calculate VLSM" class="btn btn-info" id="createButton"/>
            </div>
        </form>
       
<div>
    <a asp-action="VlsmResult">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

I created dynamically input fields as you can see from code, but I have difficulties to pass the data to controller, and to use the data for calculations inside the controller.

My question is how to pass data from dynamically created input fields with ajax to controller and how to use passed data for any kind of calculations.

Comment: Please edit your question and add in the code segment to show us your Controller's signature for the Create method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AJAX post doesn't send data .Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65932864/ajax-post-doesnt-send-data-net-core)

Comment: In that question linked above, pay attention to the Controller Method signature, as well as how the data property is defined in the AJAX call (notice how the name of the value being sent matches the parameter accepted by the method)

Comment: You keep emphasizing _dynamically created_ input fields. But there isn't really any difference whether the fields are "dynamically created" (I think you mean by JavaScript function) and explicitly defined in HTML file. Maybe create an example of such "static" HTML file that works, and show how the changes to "dynamic" make it not working. Or, if you can't do it - don't worry about fields being dynamic, and try to rewrite the question with [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model binding system will look through the property by name. So you need match the name attribute in html with model property name. That is to say, your dynamic added input fields should have name attribute:`name="LansValues[index].InitialLanValues"`.

Here is a whole working demo:

Model:

```
public class VLSM_Model
{
    public string IP_Address { get; set; }
    public List<Lans> LansValues { get; set; }
    public int cidrValue { get; set; }
}
public class Lans
{
    public int InitialLanValues { get; set; }
}
```

View:

Modify `type="submit"` to `type="button"`, otherwise the ajax will not hit.

```
@model VLSM_Model
<h1>VLSM CALCULATE</h1>
<hr />
<form asp-action="Create">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group" style="width: 35%">
        <label asp-for="IP_Address" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="IP_Address" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="IP_Address" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="form-group">
        <div id="inputFormRow" style="width: 35%">
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <br />
                <div class="input-group-append"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="newRow">
            <input type="hidden" id="totalLans" value="0" />
        </div>
        <button id="addRow" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Add Network</button>    
    </div>
    <span asp-validation-for="LansValues" class="text-danger"></span>
    <br />
    <div class="form-group" style="width: 35%">
        <label asp-for="cidrValue" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="cidrValue" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="cidrValue" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="form-group"> 
                @*change here*@
        <input type="button" value="Calculate VLSM" class="btn btn-info" id="createButton" />
    </div>
</form>

<div>
    <a asp-action="VlsmResult">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

JS:

Change the dynamic html to `name="LansValues[' + (rowCount - 1) + '].InitialLanValues"` and change `var inputData = $(this).serializeArray();` to  `var inputData = $('form').serializeArray();`.

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
    $("#addRow").click(function ()
    {
        @*@{new VLSM_Model().LansValues.Add(new Lans());}*@
        var rowCount = parseInt($("#totalLans").val());
        rowCount++;
        $("#totalLans").val(rowCount);
        var html = '';
        html += '<div id="inputFormRow" style="width: 35%">';
        html += '<div class="input-group mb-3">'; 

                //change id attribute to name attribute and modify the name
        html += '<input type="number" name="LansValues[' + (rowCount - 1) + '].InitialLanValues" class="form-control m-input" placeholder="Enter number of Hosts" autocomplete="off" style="width: 30%" required>';
        html += '<div class="input-group-append">';
        html += '<button id="removeRow" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" style="margin-right: 5px">Remove Network</button>';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '</div>';

        $('#newRow').append(html);
    });    
    $(document).on('click', '#removeRow', function ()
    {
        var rowCount = parseInt($("#totalLans").val());
        rowCount--;
        $("#totalLans").val(rowCount);
        $(this).closest('#inputFormRow').remove();
    });    
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#createButton").click(function ()
        {
            var inputData = $('form').serializeArray();   //change here...
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST", //HTTP POST Method
                url: "Home/Create", // Controller/View
                data: inputData,
                success : function(response) {
                    console.log(response)
                }
            });

        });
    });
    </script>
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create(VLSM_Model model)
    {
         //...
    }
}
```

**Note:**

Actually if you just use form submit, it also can work well. If you use form submit, just change your original code:`name="LansValues[' + (rowCount - 1) + '].InitialLanValues"`  in `$("#addRow").click()` function. Then remove the `$("#createButton").click()` function. No need change any other code.

Comment: Thank you very much, data are transferring. I will need to fine tune the controller. Because in my view aside the value there are strings which are displayed such as : LansValues
10 20 30 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[VLSMVersion_3.Models.Lans]. Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I fixed everything. I it is working perfectly. Thank you very much for your help.